# ESP8266: What can I do to overcome "section `.text' will not fit in region `iram1_0_seg'"?

Tags: linker, linker-scripts, esp8266

What are general measures against the .text region not fitting into "iram1_0_seg" when linking for the ESP8266 using the xtensa GCC based toolchain?

I guess that the ESP8266s RAM is not big enough to hold certain functions. However, what can I do to move as many functions into flash as possible?

Here is an example of what the linker returns:

```
/home/user/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/1.20.0-26-gb404fb9-2/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc  -I/home/user/git/esp-open-sdk/sdk/include -I/home/user/git/esp-open-sdk/sdk/include/json -I/home/user/git/mart3/src/RTMain/ESP8266TargetGroup -Os -D__ESP8266__ -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wpointer-arith -pipe -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Os -g -O2 -Wpointer-arith -Wundef -Wl,-EL -fno-inline-functions -nostdlib -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals  -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -L/home/user/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.0.0/tools/sdk/lib -L/home/user/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.0.0/tools/sdk/ld -Teagle.flash.512k0.ld -nostdlib -Wl,--no-check-sections -u call_user_start -Wl,-static -Wl,--gc-sections src/code/CMakeFiles/FX6CodeObj.dir/FX6Generated/src-gen/fxfu___program1.c.obj src/code/CMakeFiles/FX6CodeObj.dir/FX6Generated/src/emptyHello/fxfu___helloart.c.obj src/code/CMakeFiles/FX6CodeObj.dir/FXStd/FXRTMain.c.obj src/code/CMakeFiles/FX6CodeObj.dir/FXStd/NamedList.c.obj  -o src/ARTApp/ARTApp.out  -Wl,--start-group src/ART/libART.a -lm -lgcc -lhal -lphy -lnet80211 -llwip -lwpa -lmain -lpp -lsmartconfig -lwps -lcrypto -laxtls -Wl,--end-group
/home/user/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/1.20.0-26-gb404fb9-2/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld: src/ARTApp/ARTApp.out section `.text' will not fit in region `iram1_0_seg'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Perhaps this is too Arduino specific and you might get better answers at http://arduino.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Maybe the ```.arduino15``` in the toolchain-path is a bit misleading. I am using the toolchain but not the Arduino framework. However, I would not mind if you move this question over to the other site.

Comment: Maybe some library is using memory heavily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about Arduino but if you were to program using the Espressif libraries found here https://github.com/esp8266/esp8266-wiki/raw/master/sdk/ then they have a lot of Macros for things such as that.

As an example the "main" of the ESP is put into flash using the following line.

```
void ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR user_init(){
```

If you trace the ICACHE... command you will find this define

```
#define ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR __attribute__((section(".irom0.text")))
```

If you then look through how espressif sets up the memory sections https://github.com/esp8266/esp8266-wiki/wiki/Memory-Map .irom0.text is labelled as the flash memory. Basically anything with the ICACHE... command is loaded into flash memory anything without is not.

Again not sure how to translate this to Arduino code but it might be time to move away from the Arduino libraries if you are running out of flash space. You didn't specify which ESP breakout you are using and my mind may be playing tricks on me but I believe the ESP12-e uses a newer chip which has more flash memory then say the ESP01, just another option.

Answer (score 1):

It is a little late to answer the question but I thought others may be interested in a possible solution. This is what I have done to figure out about the iram1_0_seg overflow error on ESP8266 nonos sdk based firmware.
In order to find out what functions are actually allocated in the iram1_0_seg section run the following command:

`$ xtensa-lx106-elf-nm -av yourprogram.elf | uniq -u | grep "^4010*"`

The 'yourprogram.elf' of course needs to be replaced with the name of your firmware elf file. All iram1_0_seg functions are in the range of 4010xxxx addresses, hence the grep 4010. Obviously, this command can only be executed when the elf has been generated. If the elf file can not be generated due to the iram1_0_seg overflow error, then it is necessary to remove some code. Or roll back to a version of your code that was still fitting and did not have the iram1_0_seg overflow error.

The output of the above nm command will end with a line such as:

`$ 4010680c A _text_end`

The iram1_0_seg is limited to 0x8000 bytes on the ESP8266. In the above example, I have '0x680c' bytes allocated and therefore there is enough room. The nm command will list all functions allocated in the iram1_0_seg segment. Please look which of the functions are maybe not needed to be allocated in RAM. Most functions can run out of FLASH, but if you don't mark them with ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR, then the functions end up in RAM (and use up the 0x8000 bytes).

In case you see functions that should be in FLASH (but aren't), that actually come from the standard libraries libc.a or libgcc.a, then you have a good chance to make room in the iram1_0_seg segment. Let's take the example of memcpy, which is available in rom already and should not be needed at all in any library. The reason why it is anyway pulled from libc.a is due to the precedence that libraries take over PROVIDE statements in the linker script. Take a look at your eagle.rom.addr.v6.ld file (in your /esp-open-sdk/sdk/ld folder). In there you see the PROVIDE(memcpy=..) statement.

This tells you that memcpy is available in ROM. So, how to use the ROM function instead of the libc.a version? The easiest way is to simply remove memcpy from libc.a so that the linker takes the rom function. To be safe, I'm suggesting to make a copy of libc.a before, just in case something goes wrong. The following commands need to be executed in the library folder (where libc.a is located) in order to remove memcpy:

`$ cp libc.a libc2.a
 $ ar d libc2.a lib_a-memcpy.o`

After you have changed your Makefile to link with -lc2 instead of -lc, the 'memcpy' function will be taken from ROM. Check with the above nm command to see that it was successful. memcpy should be no more listed in the 401 list. And maybe repeat with other libc.a functions (e,g, 'memcmp', 'strlen', 'strcpy', 'strcmp', ...).
This is how I brought the iram1_0_seg usage down to 0x680c bytes.
Similar procedure can be done with libgcc.a functions: __muldf3, __mulsf3, __umulsidi3, ...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the memory allocation scheme by choosing another option in the Tools > MMU section. For example choose '16KB cache + 48KB IRAM (IRAM)' instead of '32KB cache + 32KB IRAM (balanced)'.